# Travel by Earth rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, energy

why we can't go outside the atmosphere and travel with earth rotation .. and can we travel in the opposite direction of atmosphere by the same speed of atmosphere it’s moving at about 1,000 miles an hour  .. atmosphere speed will be 0 and we can travel by Earth rotation ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gNkgj9h2oM You should watch this.

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear, could you provide some more context & clean up the formatting of your question?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** travel with just moving up , waiting then landing.

When you are staying at the surface of the earth, you are moving with the velocity of the surface of the earth. This is because you are attached to it.

If you ride on a balloon and just elevate and go up, you have the velocity that you had on the surface of the earth. but as you have gone farther from the center of the earth, you should have more velocity to have the same ANGULAR velocity of the earth ($\omega = r v$).
BUT you have less.

This causes that you lag from earth and when you land, you will find yourself not where you started the trip.

of course you should go very high for wind not to affect you. there, you won't be able to breathe as the air pressure is very low.

Answer (score 0):

Because of inertia: we are rotating together with the earth. Imagine this: you are on a car travelling through a highway and you want to stop at a given point A. For experimental reasons, let's not count with air friction (because there's no air in space). If you jump off the car's roof exactly at point A whilst the car is still moving, you'll land right back on top of the car, but further away. If you were to jump earlier, you could manage to land on point A (if your timing is right), but you'd still land on the car.

In order to actually get off at point A, you would need to jump off the car at the same speed and opposite direction at which the car is moving. This means a lot of energy and effort.

*EDIT* a balloon would be pushed by the wind and get you nowhere, as they can't float up to inner space.

So, If we were to shoot out to space and then fall back down, we'd still land exactly where we took off from, unless we pushed ourselves at the same speed at which the earth rotates, which would be a whopping 400 m/s. Plus, shooting out to space is pretty expensive on its own, it wouldn't be a viable method of transport.

**TL;DR It's way too complicated and expensive, even just to get to inner space**

***RE-EDIT: THE THEORY APPLIED TO THE CAR CANNOT BE TRANSFERRED TO THE EARTH DUE TO THE DIFFERENCE IN TYPES OF MOMENTUM (LINEAR AND ANGULAR). THE METHOD OF TRANSPORT WOULD BE POSSIBLE.***   It would still be hella expensive though...

Comment: This is true if the motion is linear. Earth rotates. sot he motion is angular. you are wrong to say you will land on the same point that you took off.

Comment: @bluesky angular momentum is larger the further away you get from the center of rotation or something, but still, for this type of transport to work you'd have to travel to space, which is really expensive (my main point). I'll edit my errors. You are absolutely right, btw.

Comment: When you detached from the earth, you are no longer in its coordinate system and therefore no longer experiencing ITS angular momentum. the only thing affecting you is the gravity which is not in conflict with the motion.